# Possible to run SBT-Commands in Shell-Script?

Tags: shell, sbt

is it possible to run sbt commands in a shell script?

Something like

```
cd path/to/project
sbt
project xyz
run x
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html):

> Batch mode
>
> You can run sbt in batch mode, specifying a space-separated list of sbt commands as arguments. For sbt commands that take arguments, pass the command and arguments as one argument to sbt by enclosing them in quotes. For example,

```
$ sbt clean compile "testOnly TestA TestB"
```

In your case, following line should do the trick:

`$ sbt "project xyz" "run x"`